# How to get query colums as String

Tags: rust, mysql-connector

I'm porting a PHP-app to  Rust (as a noob). Since my query results will go straight into html, I don't really need any type-safety. Just NULL -> "" and everything else as String.

Also `time::PrimitiveDateTime` doesn't fully implement format, such that {mytime:.19} doesn't cut off the useless ".0" milliseconds. So it'd be nice to have that as String too. Unless there is an easier conversion to get that?

Not having found (or understood) any appropriate converter, I tried

```
fn as_string(row: mysql::Row, index: usize) -> String {
    if let Some(&value) = row.as_ref(index) {
        value.to_string()
    } else {
        String::from("")
    }
}
```

but

```
error[E0599]: `mysql::Value` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
```

Comment: Rather than using database models directly, I'd suggest creating your own struct and implementing `Display` for that.  `Display` is what provides the `to_string` method.

Comment: In practice, you would create a `new` method that takes the `mysql::Row`, assign your struct fields, then use those fields in the `to_string` "override".

Comment: If this is some webapi where this is being turned into a response, you could implement `serde::Serialize` instead of `Display` and use your framework to return _that_.

Comment: I was hoping for something lightweight, as I have many pages with many complex queries. Not even obvious which columns might be NULL, and not wanting to write a lot of boilerplate for each query. Instead as gemeric as possible, a no-brainer to use!

Comment: Which dependency are you using for `mysql`?  Might be extra features you can enable where someone has already done the boilerplate.

Comment: Open for suggestions. I have `mysql = "*"`, `time = "*"` and `serde = { version = "*", features = ["derive"] }`

Comment: Sounds like you want [`from_value`](https://docs.rs/mysql/latest/mysql/#fromvalue-trait) to convert from `Value` to the inner `T`

Comment: In principle yes. But I'm bewildered. For one thing, why does `as_ref` return an `Option`, when `NULL` is a `Value`? And mainly, how would this look, at least for one `T`?

Comment: @Daniel `as_ref` returns an `Option`, because you can move values out of the `Row` object via `Row::take`. And if you try to `as_ref` an element that you already moved out before, you will get `None`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `value` variable is of type [`mysql::Value`](https://docs.rs/mysql/22.2.0/mysql/enum.Value.html), which is an `Enum` type.

As it doesn't implement `Display`, you probably want to write a conversion to `String` manually.

For enums, this usually involves a `match`:

```rust
use mysql::Value;

fn as_string(mut row: mysql::Row, index: usize) -> String {
    if let Some(value) = row.as_ref(index) {
        match value {
            Value::NULL => String::from(""),
            Value::Bytes(v) => String::from_utf8_lossy(v.as_slice()).into_owned(),
            Value::Int(v) => format!("{v}"),
            Value::UInt(v) => format!("{v}"),
            Value::Float(v) => format!("{v}"),
            Value::Double(v) => format!("{v}"),
            Value::Date(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, micro) => todo!(),
            Value::Time(negative, days, hours, minutes, seconds, micro) => todo!(),
        }
    } else {
        String::from("")
    }
}
```

You should of course replace the `todo!()` statements with implementations for those specific types.

---

Note that you shouldn't actually handle the `None` case like this, because it indicates a programming error. It happens if you already moved the value out of `Row` before, **not** if your cell is empty.

So I would argue the cleanest way is to return an `Option<String>`, which simplifies this function even further:

```rust
use mysql::Value;

fn as_string(mut row: mysql::Row, index: usize) -> Option<String> {
    row.as_ref(index).map(|value| match value {
        Value::NULL => String::from(""),
        Value::Bytes(v) => String::from_utf8_lossy(v.as_slice()).into_owned(),
        Value::Int(v) => format!("{v}"),
        Value::UInt(v) => format!("{v}"),
        Value::Float(v) => format!("{v}"),
        Value::Double(v) => format!("{v}"),
        Value::Date(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, micro) => todo!(),
        Value::Time(negative, days, hours, minutes, seconds, micro) => todo!(),
    })
}
```

Comment: My String bit is messy so far (from something I found in the mysql crate source), but at least it works: `unsafe { String::from_utf8_unchecked(v.to_vec()) }`

Comment: @Daniel You mean the 'Bytes'? **DON'T DO THAT!** That is very unsafe, everyone who has access to the database has the power to break your program. This is definitely undefined behaviour. Use the safe version [`from_utf8_lossy`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html#method.from_utf8_lossy) instead. I updated the example to include it. Especially if it is data you can't control (like from a database) you **never** want to call an `_unchecked` function.

Answer (score 0):

Since this potentially runs frequently, I ended up avoiding expensive Strings on the heap. Instead, on the outside I declare a 28(+4) byte string on the stack for each expected column. And I return a reference to them where needed (i.e. formatted values):

```rust
pub type TmpString = ArrayString<28>;

/// Helper to convert any DB Value to a &str, into the provided empty buf, or byte[] from the query
/// NULL as ""
pub fn value_to_str<'a>(buf: &'a mut TmpString, value: &'a Value) -> &'a str {
    match value {
        // no need for $param, where we can directly use &str
        Value::NULL => return "",
        Value::Bytes(v) => {
            return std::str::from_utf8(v).unwrap_or_else(|_| {
                let alt = String::from_utf8_lossy(v);
                error!("invalid UTF-8: {alt}");
                // Return max buf.capacity() bytes of lossy UTF-8
                let mut len = alt.len().min(buf.capacity());
                while !alt.is_char_boundary(len) {
                    len -= 1
                }
                write!(buf, "{}", &alt[..len]).unwrap();
                buf
            })
        }

        // All should fit into TmpString, but just in case, unwrap says which param overflows.
        Value::Int(v) => write!(buf, "{v}").unwrap(),
        Value::UInt(v) => write!(buf, "{v}").unwrap(),
        Value::Float(v) => write!(buf, "{v}").unwrap(),
        Value::Double(v) => write!(buf, "{v}").unwrap(),
        Value::Date(year, month, day, hour, minutes, seconds, _micro) => write!(
            buf,
            "{year}-{month:02}-{day:02} {hour:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}"
        )
        .unwrap(),
        Value::Time(negative, days, hours, minutes, seconds, _micro) => {
            if *negative {
                write!(buf, "-").unwrap();
            }
            if *days > 0 {
                write!(buf, "{days}-").unwrap();
            }
            write!(buf, "{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}").unwrap();
        }
    }
    buf
}
```